# ASP.NET mvc display int number in LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Why it's displaying `data`, but not the value `100`

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    ViewBag.id = 100;
    return View();
 }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model TestForm.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.data,((int)@ViewBag.id))
}
```

Comment: Your value is in the ViewBag and not the Model, you will need to return View(new Data(){data = 100});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the '@' if you want to display `100` that you stuffed into a ViewBag

Viewbag:

```
ViewBag.id = "100";
```

Html:

```
@model TestForm.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.data,((string /*LabelFor produces string lableText */)ViewBag.id))
}
```

Or:

```
@Html.Label("id", (int)ViewBag.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the LabelFor, you could always do the following:

```
<label>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Id)</label>
```

LabelFor is really reserved for Model properties since the model is able to pass Data Types and Data Annotations like Email, Password.

By doing it the more raw HTML way, you can style is appropriately like you would any other HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `100` on label text, then why are you using `Html.LabelFor`? The first parameter of `LabelFor` shows the text of the property (or the `DisplayAttribute` inside your model), which in your case is `data`.

Use `Html.Label` instead, like this

```
@Html.Label("id", (int)ViewBag.id)
```

Or, in a simply way, use the html version:

```
<label>ViewBag.id</label>
```